# Vue iterate loop json placeholder

Tags: vuejs2

I´m trying to retrieve in Vue (with axios) a json users . Apparently it works but i can´t (or maybe i don´t know) how can i iterate all array elements. The question is simple ¿how works a loop in Vue2?

```
<script>
      import axios from 'axios';
      export default {
        data() {
          return {
            users: []
          }
        }
      }
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response)=>{  
        this.users = response.data
        console.log(this.users);
      })
    </script>

     //Loop

       <ul>
            <li v-for="user in users" :key="user.name">
              <p>
                <strong>{{user.name}}</strong>
              </p>
              <p>{{user.email}}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: Are you getting proper response in `console.log(this.users)`?

Comment: Yes. this.users has proper response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code (if it's not a copy paste typo) is your axios call is droped inside the script section in no proper way so when you do `this.user = data` you will never reach the user property of the component, your fuctions must be inside `methods` property or in a lifecicle hook like `mounted` in order to work as you spect.

Example on a correct way to do it:

```
methods: {
  loadUsers () {
    axios.get(...).then(users => this.users = users)
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.loadUsers()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried with

```
    export default {
            data() {
              return {
                userss: []
              }
            },
            beforeMount : function()
            {
                this.userss.push({name: 'bob', email: 'bob@'});
                this.userss.push({name: 'maria', email: 'maria@'});
                console.log('alex : ', this.userss);
                console.log('alex2: ', this.userss[0].name);
                console.log('alex3: ', this.userss[1].name);
          }

and 

                      <ul>
                        <li v-for="user in userss" :key="user.name">
                          <p>
                            <strong>{{user.name}}</strong>
                          </p>
                          <p>{{user.email}}</p>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
```

and i have a good result :[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEoc4.png)

i printed yo the console i have :

[test console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re6qE.png)

i think you don't get your results the good way :

```
> axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response)=>{  
        this.users = response.data
        console.log(this.users);
      })
```

if you try  `console.log(this.users);` outside the loop, you won't have the same thing than me

i think you have to try to get your users inside  a beforemount :

```
 <script>
          import axios from 'axios';
          export default {
            data() {
              return {
                users: []
              }
            },
           beforeMount : function()
            {
            axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response)=>{  
               this.users = response.data
             })
            console.log(this.users);
            }
          }

        </script>

         //Loop

           <ul>
                <li v-for="user in users" :key="user.name">
                  <p>
                    <strong>{{user.name}}</strong>
                  </p>
                  <p>{{user.email}}</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
```